# Get the list of Audio Output Devices inside Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to get all the available speakers in current device. And populate them as a dropdown options.
When selecting the particular option in unity, I need to switch the audio playing to that particular speaker device.

And I want the same methods for android devices to like switching between bluetooth and earpiece.

I know there is no simple method to get the list of speakers available in Unity C#. Like the `Microphone.devices` class. But is there any other simple method to access the devices?.

Answer (score 0):

There's no simple way to do it at all. Basically two options

1. Use some plugin from AssetStore like [this](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/audio/audiostream-pcm-audio-for-unity-65411)
2. Use FMOD as alternative to unity audio system and use [setDriver](https://www.fmod.com/docs/2.02/api/core-api-system.html#system_setdriver) to control output device

But I doubt that any option actually worth it unless you do an audio editor